# Subscript out of Range Error when trying to check other values in array

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array

I have seem to run into a weird issue I cant see, to figure out. Everything works fine until it tries to look three steps forward. Which is weird because in other set ups this works fine? (Nested IF's).

Anyone have some insight?

```
Dim CFArray (37,1) As Date

Select Case Stuff

    Case Is <> CFArray(l, 0)
        If Stuff > CFArray(l, 0) Then
            For m = LBound(CFArray, 2) To UBound(CFArray, 2)
                If Stuff < CFArray(l, m) Then
                    Stuff = CFArray(l + 1, 0)
                    Stuff2 = CFArray(l + 1, m)
                End If
            Next m
        End If

        If Stuff > CFArray(l + 1, 0) Then
            For m = LBound(CFArray, 2) To UBound(CFArray, 2)
                If Stuff < CFArray(l + 1, m) Then
                    Stuff = CFArray(l + 2, 0)
                    Stuff2 = CFArray(l + 2, m)
                End If
            Next m
        End If

        If Stuff > CFArray(l + 2, 0) Then  *this is where it trips up, the value is the third step in the array?
            For m = LBound(CFArray, 2) To UBound(CFArray, 2)
                If Stuff < CFArray(l + 2, m) Then
                    Stuff = CFArray(l + 3, 0)
                    Stuff2 = CFArray(l + 3, m)
                End If
            Next m
        End If

End Select
```

Comment: You have a typo here: `If Stuff > FArray(l + 1, 0) Then` should be `CFArray(l +1,0)`

Comment: Stuff is an array, I don't see how the Select case cans work. And can you show us how CFArray is defined?

Comment: @VincentG thanks for that, corrected. However not the solution sadly

Comment: Also corrected. Typos and such, sorry about that

Comment: And what is the value of `l` when the error occurs? I suspect 35?

Comment: @VincentG the value was the value contained in CFArray(3, 0).

Comment: Are you saying `l` was 1, then?

Comment: Let me recreate error and get back to you :)

Comment: @VincentG L is actually = to 36

Comment: Then L + 2 is 38 and your array only goes to 37, so you need to put a check in to not do that if when L >= 36 and on the the one prior the same for >=37.

Comment: Apparently i was looking at the value of Stuff and not l

Comment: We prefer questions without salutations, regards, signatures etc here. Please also don't address readers with male pronouns - it is rather exclusionary! Thanks.